# Cplex definition of variables

Tags: linear-programming, cplex, ampl

Firstly I am newly with cplex, i want to define R as a set of two pairs (i,j) and then write the below constrains:

```
zij ∈ {0, 1},                                        ∀ i, j s.t.(i, j) ∈ R
fj − fi ≥ 0 − M(1 − zij ),                           ∀ i, j s.t.(i, j) ∈ R 
fi − fj ≥ E − Mzij ,                                 ∀ i, j s.t.(i, j) ∈ R
```

Noting:
E is a very small positive number
M is a “sufficiently large” number
and I have defined f as dvar int+ f[channels];

Comment: @
Alex Fleischer

Answer (score 0):

You could start with

```
int M=1000;
int E=2;

range R=1..10;

dvar boolean z[R,R];
dvar int+ f[R];
subject to
{
  
  forall(i,j in R) 
  {
    f[j]-f[i]>=0-M*(1-z[i][j]);
    f[j]-f[i]>=E-M*z[i,j];
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment dr. Alex, but i want to declare Zij as two possibilities variable that need to be encoded in the optimization formulation in order to preserve linearity in the constrains so how to define the Zij to take either value of (0) or to take the value of (1) to be deployed in the next constrains. thanks in advance

Comment: boolean means z will be either 0 or 1

Comment: Thank u, how to test these functions                                                                        
     cons02:  
      forall(a in R) firstchannel[a.j]-firstchannel[a.i]>= 0-M*(1- Z[a]);
      cons02_1:  
      forall(a in R) firstchannel[a.i]-firstchannel[a.j]>= E- Z[a];